# RabbitMQ server throws an error but locally it is working perfectly fine

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Setup:

1. Masstransit verion: 2.10
2. RabbitMq Client: 3.4.3.0
3. RabbitMq Server : 3.5.3  (used default ports and configurations)
4. Erlang 17.5

I can access the RabbitMQ web management client and able use the rabbitMQ locally. The problem is deployed in data center.

the code:

```
 ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq(r => r.ConfigureHost(new Uri("rabbitmq://actual-server-name/queue-name"), h =>
            {
                h.SetUsername("username");
                h.SetPassword("password");
            }));
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://actual-server-name/queue-name");
            sbc.Subscribe(x => x.LoadFrom(container));
        });
```

I got an exception error:
It came from MassTransit.Exceptions.MassTransitException. When you dig down inside it from RabbitMQ itself.

RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException : None of the specified endpoints were reacheable.

System.IO.Exception : connection.start was never received, likely to a network timeout. found in Masstransit.ServiceContainer.cs line: 63

Why it throwing error; since the rabbitmq server installation is same in my local setting? permission issue? firewall issue?

Comment: are you using "guest" "guest" as username and password?

Comment: Yes and created new account the problem still the same. Morever, i restarted my development machine including the rabbitmq server; I never face this problem.

Comment: The answers are as described, the vhost must already exist. Otherwise, the credentials won't have access to the virtual host (because, again, it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Hi, any solution for this exception?

Comment: @krishnachaitanya I never tried the latest version now. I resolved the problem before by creating manually the vhost in RMQ and provide correct permission before this call

Answer (score 1):

I observed and verified in my testing; masstransit does not allow creating of vhost from uri input. RabbitMQ will throw most likely the same error.

To resolve this issue, create the vhost and queue manually in rabbitmq server.

*PS. I knew, this is not the same as the question ask.*

Comment: reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/L4CnzPMN02Q

Answer (score 0):

One can create the queue through the code but not the vhost. So, you have to create the vhost manually and also give proper permissions to access via code.